# flutter android studio reload not performed analysis issues found

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I press command+s on a specific file, I get the below error.

error: reload not performed analysis issues found

Clicking the lightning icon hot reload works fine.

And if you command+left click a class in the file mentioned above, it does not move to that class.

error: cannot find declaration to go to

The peculiarity is that, as mentioned above, it does not work only on certain files.

flutter doctor -v no problem.
I've also tried flutter clean, invalidate caches/restart but it doesn't work.

Comment: Many of them had the same issue. But there is no  solution for it yet